How to disable mouse wheel in python tkinter with certain condition?
self.loginWindow.bind("<MouseWheel>",
                         lambda event: self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units"))

This was supposed to enable the scroll wheel in my tkinter project, but the problem is i want to stop that in a specific condition.
How to do that ?
I tried to make it this way
self.loginWindow.bind(None)


but it is not working

Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

You can Try
if (anything):
   self.loginWindow.bind("<MouseWheel>",
                          lambda event: None)
else:
     (otherwise)

This will stop the mouse wheel events
